# php prevent parent from accessing child properties

Tags: php, oop

the question is simple. I have a base abstract class (person). From this i have extended another class (patients).

I save personal information (e.g. firstname, lastname) in PERSONS table [there is an ADD function. ]. Patient specific information (like illness, medicines, ...) are saved into a separate PATIENTS class. [there is an ADD function that calls the parent, then some code].

How do I prevent person's add function from accessing properties defined inside it's child, patients?

In order to make it more clear, here is a sample code:

```
class P {
public P_var = 'Anoush' ; 
public function add ()
{
  // find all properties:
  foreach ($this as $prop => $val )
  {
     $insertables [$prop] = $val ; 
  }
  // insert all VALUES FIELDSET etc. based on the array created above 

}

class CH extends P {
public CH_var1 = 'ravan' ; 
public CH_var2 = 'something' ; 
}
```

Then when I call add, the `$insertables` will contain P_var, CH_var1 , CH_var2. I only want it to have P_var.

Thanks

Comment: If `patient` properties are not `public`, the parent class won't be able to see them.

Comment: In this situation, is there anyway I can use the `person` object only without additives provided by the child ?

Comment: You will need to post more code so we can see your class implementations.  The child classes do not pass anything added back up to the parent, and if the parent is `abstract`, it cannot be instantiated itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using Reflection (see http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php).

```
class Parent {
    public function add() {
        $insertables = $this->_getOwnProperties(__CLASS__);
        // ...
    }

    protected function _getOwnProperties($className) {
        $reflection = new ReflectionClass($this);
        $props = array();

        foreach ($reflection->getProperties() as $name => $prop) {
            if ($prop->class == $className) {
                $props[$name] = $prop;
            }
        }

        return $props;
    }
}
```

However, I recommend refactoring your code instead to get a cleaner solution (e.g. add a method `getProperties()` (maybe defined by an interface) or whatever. Then let your database class invoke that function in order to get the list of properties to store in the database.

Comment: Can you elaborate, where should I put this ? a function inside the parent abstract class?